# how do I convert a n rows to a single row in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I'm trying to convert a pd.series to a pd.df
I have the next df:

```
   COL1
0   a
1   b 
2   c
3   d
4   e
5   f
.   .
.   .
n   n
```

I need to convert it like this:

```
   COL1 COL2 COL3
0   a    b    c
1   d    e    f
.   .    .    .
.   .    .    .
n   n    n    n
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `reshape`

```
out = pd.DataFrame(df.COL1.values.reshape((-1,3)))
Out[243]: 
   0  1  2
0  a  b  c
1  d  e  f
```